# Plot validation loss in Tensorflow Object Detection API

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorboard, object-detection-api, loss

I'm using Tensorflow Object Detection API for detection and localization of one class object in images. For these purposes, I use the pre-trained `faster_rcnn_resnet50_coco_2018_01_28` model.

I want to detect under/overfitting after training the model. I see training loss, but after evaluating Tensorboard only shows mAP and Precision metrics and no loss.

Is this possible to plot a validation loss on Tensorboard too?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is validation loss.
Assuming you're using the latest API, the curve under "loss" is validation loss while "loss_1/2" is the training loss.

Comment: Is there a link to the documentation on this? I always end up at this answer, but it would be nice to have some official docs to cite.

Answer (score 4):

To see the validation curve you should change faster_rcnn_resnet50_coco.config:

1- comment `max_evals` line
2- set `eval_interval_secs`: 60 .
3- num_examples should be equal or less than the number of "files" that you have in "val.record" .

```
eval_config: { . 
  num_examples: 600 . 
  eval_interval_secs: 60 . 
  # Note: The below line limits the evaluation process to 10 evaluations.  
  # Remove the below line to evaluate indefinitely.  
  # max_evals: 10 .
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using model_main.py for training gives two curves in tensorboard. They supposed to be train and validation losses.

you can use the following command at CMD.

python object_detection/model_main.py --num_eval_steps=10 --num_train_steps=50000 --alsologtostderr --pipeline_config_path=C:/DroneMaskRCNN/DroneMaskRCNN1/mask_rcnn_inception_v2_coco.config  --model_dir=C:/DroneMaskRCNN/DroneMaskRCNN1/CP

Comment: this isn't really an answer, this should have been a comment

Comment: Please explain how this answers the question and move everything else into a comment on your own post (which is possible even without the commenting privilege). Obviously this must be an answer, because somebody upvoted it, but I just do not see how...

Comment: I got loss_1 and loss_2, but they are the same. They look like they represent a training loss.

I made the conf file like this:

    eval_config: { . 
      num_examples: 104.  # must equals the number of your validation examples
      eval_interval_secs: 60 . # time to make validation after 60 seconds, the normal one is 300 seconds
      
    }