# TF2 Object Detection API: model_main_tf2.py - validation loss?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, object-detection, object-detection-api

I have been trying to train an object detection model for past 2 months and have finally succeeded by following this [tutorial](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Here is my [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Dn3bgYkialkPXImM1XWaYqjgVNTGI9Fn?usp=sharing) which contains all my work.

The problem is, the training loss is shown, and it is decreasing on average, but the validation loss is not.

In the `pipeline.config` file, I did input the evaluation TFRecord file (which I assumed to be the validation data input) , like this:

> eval_config {
>
> metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics"
>
> use_moving_averages: false
>
> }
>
> eval_input_reader {
>
> label_map_path: "annotations/label_map.pbtxt"
>
> shuffle: false
>
> num_epochs: 1
>
> tf_record_input_reader {
>
> input_path: "annotations/test.record"
>
> }
>
> }

and I read through [model_main_tf2.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py), which does not seem to evaluation while training, but only evaluates when the checkpoint_dir is mentioned.

Hence, I have only been able to monitor the loss on the training set and not the loss on the validation set.

As a result, I have no clue about over or under fitting.

**Have any of you managed to use model_main_tf2.py successfully to view validation loss?**

Also, it would be nice to see the mAP score with training.

I know keras training allows all these things to be seen on tensorboard, but OD API seems to be much harder.

Thank you for your time, if you are still confused about something please let me know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plot validation loss in Tensorflow Object Detection API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52849514/plot-validation-loss-in-tensorflow-object-detection-api)

Comment: i will try it and let you know

Comment: Update, i don't see the loss, screeenshots of all my losses: 
https://ibb.co/RHc65Qr
https://ibb.co/NsV0dPG
https://ibb.co/m965S5t
https://ibb.co/80qSYG8
https://ibb.co/mvft3k6

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to open **another terminal** and run this command

```
python model_main_tf2.py \
   --model_dir=models/my_ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn \
   --pipeline_config_path=models/my_ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn/pipeline.config \
   --checkpoint_dir=models/my_ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn
```

This [API tutorial](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html#evaluating-the-model-optional) is unclear on that topic. I had the exact same issue.

It turns out that the evaluation process is not included in the training loop, you must launch it in **parallel**.

It will wait and say `waiting for new checkpoint`, which means that when you will launch a training with:

```sh
python model_main_tf2.py --model_dir=models/my_ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn --pipeline_config_path=models/my_ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn/pipeline.config # note that the checkpoint_dir argument is not there
```

It's going to run the evaluation once every `eval_interval_secs` in your `eval_config`.

According to the documentation, the eval metrics will the be stored next to your checkpoints inside a eval_0 directory, which you will then be able to plot in tensorboard.

I do agree that this was a bit hard to understand as it is not very clear in the documentation, and is not very convenient as well since I had to allocate another GPU to do the evaluation to avoid the CUDA out of memory issue.

Have a nice day

Comment: You just cleared it up, thanks so much. So now I have to open another colab and then install the api and then run the eval command. :) :) :) thanks google.

Comment: Hello, I am following the tuto, and when I use `python model_main_tf2.py --model_dir=models/my_ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn --pipeline_config_path=models/my_ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn/pipeline.config # note that the checkpoint_dir argument is not there` I have utf-8 codec can't  decode byte 0x92 error... any idea why ?

Comment: I followed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IOI0o3Cxv9Q&list=PL5gqy7xDV-OSivyzcO6-oV3_lj5ief7kb&index=6&t=2433s and worked. model_main_tf2.py --model_dir={}/{} --pipeline_config_path={}/{}/pipeline.config --num_train_steps=5000". When you download the model zoo, you have the check point.

Comment: thank you bro, someone need to update or clarify the doc of that tutorial , i have the same problem and confusion as us .