# Why TensorFlow object detection 2.x don't show mAP when training the model

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0, object-detection

I used TF 1.4 to train some object detection models in the past, and I remember that the evaluation during the training shows the mAP of the model. My problem is that now, on TF 2.5, these metrics are not shown, and I need this to evaluate my success. This is my only output:

```
I0715 00:57:35.858141 140071375349632 model_lib_v2.py:701] {'Loss/classification_loss': 0.19326138,
 'Loss/localization_loss': 0.07984769,
 'Loss/regularization_loss': 0.2631261,
 'Loss/total_loss': 0.5362352,
 'learning_rate': 0.03066655}
```

I've trained the model for 2k steps and nothing... I can't evaluate my model just based on loss. How can I print again mAP?

This is my pipeline config file (I'm using SSD with Resnet 50):

```
model {
  ssd {
    num_classes: 3
    image_resizer {
      fixed_shape_resizer {
        height: 640
        width: 640
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: "ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn_keras"
      depth_multiplier: 1.0
      min_depth: 16
      conv_hyperparams {
        regularizer {
          l2_regularizer {
            weight: 0.00039999998989515007
          }
        }
        initializer {
          truncated_normal_initializer {
            mean: 0.0
            stddev: 0.029999999329447746
          }
        }
        activation: RELU_6
        batch_norm {
          decay: 0.996999979019165
          scale: true
          epsilon: 0.0010000000474974513
        }
      }
      override_base_feature_extractor_hyperparams: true
      fpn {
        min_level: 3
        max_level: 7
      }
    }
    box_coder {
      faster_rcnn_box_coder {
        y_scale: 10.0
        x_scale: 10.0
        height_scale: 5.0
        width_scale: 5.0
      }
    }
    matcher {
      argmax_matcher {
        matched_threshold: 0.5
        unmatched_threshold: 0.5
        ignore_thresholds: false
        negatives_lower_than_unmatched: true
        force_match_for_each_row: true
        use_matmul_gather: true
      }
    }
    similarity_calculator {
      iou_similarity {
      }
    }
    box_predictor {
      weight_shared_convolutional_box_predictor {
        conv_hyperparams {
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 0.00039999998989515007
            }
          }
          initializer {
            random_normal_initializer {
              mean: 0.0
              stddev: 0.009999999776482582
            }
          }
          activation: RELU_6
          batch_norm {
            decay: 0.996999979019165
            scale: true
            epsilon: 0.0010000000474974513
          }
        }
        depth: 256
        num_layers_before_predictor: 4
        kernel_size: 3
        class_prediction_bias_init: -4.599999904632568
      }
    }
    anchor_generator {
      multiscale_anchor_generator {
        min_level: 3
        max_level: 7
        anchor_scale: 4.0
        aspect_ratios: 1.0
        aspect_ratios: 2.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.5
        scales_per_octave: 2
      }
    }
    post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 9.99999993922529e-09
        iou_threshold: 0.6000000238418579
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 100
        use_static_shapes: false
      }
      score_converter: SIGMOID
    }
    normalize_loss_by_num_matches: true
    loss {
      localization_loss {
        weighted_smooth_l1 {
        }
      }
      classification_loss {
        weighted_sigmoid_focal {
          gamma: 2.0
          alpha: 0.25
        }
      }
      classification_weight: 1.0
      localization_weight: 1.0
    }
    encode_background_as_zeros: true
    normalize_loc_loss_by_codesize: true
    inplace_batchnorm_update: true
    freeze_batchnorm: false
  }
}
train_config {
  batch_size: 8
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_crop_image {
      min_object_covered: 0.0
      min_aspect_ratio: 0.75
      max_aspect_ratio: 3.0
      min_area: 0.75
      max_area: 1.0
      overlap_thresh: 0.0
    }
  }
  sync_replicas: true
  optimizer {
    momentum_optimizer {
      learning_rate {
        cosine_decay_learning_rate {
          learning_rate_base: 0.03999999910593033
          total_steps: 25000
          warmup_learning_rate: 0.013333000242710114
          warmup_steps: 2000
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.8999999761581421
    }
    use_moving_average: false
  }
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "/content/models/research/pretrained_model/ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn_640x640_coco17_tpu-8/checkpoint/ckpt-0"
  num_steps: 2100
  startup_delay_steps: 0.0
  replicas_to_aggregate: 8
  max_number_of_boxes: 100
  unpad_groundtruth_tensors: false
  fine_tune_checkpoint_type: "detection"
  use_bfloat16: true
  fine_tune_checkpoint_version: V2
}
train_input_reader {
  label_map_path: "/content/label_map.pbtxt"
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "/content/train.record"
  }
}
eval_config {
  metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics"
  use_moving_averages: false
}
eval_input_reader {
  label_map_path: "/content/label_map.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_epochs: 1
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "/content/test.record"
  }
}
```

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64535040/4710226) for some details (evaluation interval and GPU memory concern).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run the `model_main_tf2.py` script in two shells simultaneously.

In the first shell, you run it with arguments `--model_dir` and `--pipeline_config_path`, for training, like below:

```sh
python model_main_tf2.py --model_dir my-model --pipeline_config_path my-model/pipeline.config --alsologtostderr
```

In the second shell, you need to pass an extra argument called `--checkpoint_dir`, pointing to the folder where checkpoints are stored, like below:

```sh
python model_main_tf2.py --model_dir my-model --pipeline_config_path my-model/pipeline.config --checkpoint_dir my-model
```

This will trigger evaluation mode of the script, and TensorBoard will start to show mAP and recall metrics.

Comment: Thank you, after all, this is the solution that I'm following, I need to use two Colab notebooks at the same time, it's not so practical, but works!

Answer (score 1):

In TF 2.5 ,you can use `model.summary to see model configuration . metrics (loss ,accuracy ,learning rate ) can be changed in model.compile` . you can see  value of parameters  live during model.fit operation    . Attaching following document for your reference
https://www.tensorflow.org/js/guide/models_and_layers https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/train_and_evaluate ,           you can also  create custom metrics upon default metrics to test the model while training the model